# Dataflow job drain does not end and system latency grows for a long time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

We have a dataflow pipeline that ends with either

- send a PubSub message to "Done" topic  OR
- send a PubSub message to "DLQ" or "RETRY" topic

Here is the graph for data pipeline:

[image: data pipeline]

and here is the system latency issue although all 6 elements processed successfully :

[image: system latency]

For the scenarios when we have some messages sent on both topics, dataflow does not recognize a successful end and system latency grows and draining gets stuck!

Comment: if possible, can you elaborate more on your usecase and possibly share the pipeline code.

Comment: I added the pipeline graph to make it more clear, thanks.

Comment: Thats strange. To better investigate this issue, we might need to take a look at job specific log and metrics. I would recommend opening a ticket with the support team.

Comment: As @Ankur said, I would recommend you to open a support ticket if you have a support package. Otherwise, please open an issue in the [public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out that the incident happens when you miss the pub/sub topic, specifically in our case DLQ topic was forgotten to be created.